# What is the meaning of the phrase "solitō māiōre"?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, grammar-identification, nuntii-latini

A fellow member of a Latin Discord server I participate in posted [this link](https://areena.yle.fi/1-4256713?autoplay=true) to an article with a question regarding how one would interpret the phrase *"solitō māiōre"*. Despite our efforts to interpret it, we couldn't come up with any meaningful literal(-ish) translation. Google (and other search engines) yielded no fruitful results either, with the only meaningful information gained being the knowledge that it was likely an epigram or idiom of some kind (which was often labeled with "Aus. *Epigr.* 56.3" in the results I could find).

What does this phrase, *"solitō māiōre"*, mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For reference, the full clause is:

> Postridie Nonas Decembres (6.12.2017) anniversarium independentiae Finnorum solito maiore pompa celebratum est.

*maiore* is feminine ablative singular and modifies *pompa* (= *pompā*).

*solito* is a neuter singular ablative (of comparison), and provides the second term in the comparison. There's the usual amount of pomp, but the pomp on this occasion was greater than that usual amount.

The whole clause means:

> On the day before the Nones of December, the anniversary of Finnish independence was celebrated with greater pomp than (what is) usual.

This use of *solito* with a comparative is quite common. For example, there's Ovid *Metamorphoses* 7.84–85 (Jason & Medea):

> et casu solito formosior Aesone natus
>   illa luce fuit.
>
> And by chance, the son of Aeson was on that day more handsome than usual.